# vs2019 C# console app does not run as expected

Tags: .net-core, console-application, visual-studio-2019

Visual Studio 2019 is not creating and executing a console app like previous versions of VS.

If I open a new project, put this code in Main():

```
        Console.WriteLine("hello");
        Console.ReadKey();
```

and hit F5, the app appears to run, then exit with code 0. The console doesn't wait for a key input to close, and breakpoints in the source do not hit.

The EXE should be in this folder
    c:\projects\test-app\bin\debug\

but it is actually in:
    c:\projects\test-app\bin\debug\netcoreapp3.0

and when I run it from that location outside the IDE it opens a console and immediately closes it, apparently not running the code in Main().

Going through the exact same steps with Visual Studio 2017 runs the app as expected.

I can live with the final exe being located to a different folder but VS2019 doesn't even seem to be running any of my code. Am I missing something?

Comment: It seems, that `c:\projects\test-app\bin\debug\` is output path for .NET framework app and `c:\projects\test-app\bin\debug\netcoreapp3.0` is for .NET Core. Try to create the app for the same targets and check the behavior. .NET Core app runs through `dotnet` CLI

Comment: That is the problem; I opened a .NET <CORE> C# console app instead of a .net <FRAMEWORK> app. VS2019 changed the method of choosing a new project template, and I didn't notice the difference. So I was indeed 'missing something'.